# How to extract field from a REDSHIFT JSON type column?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Trying to extract value stored after key **threeDSEci** i.e. "01" .Unable to understand what does these s:5/s:2 etc. means here.

**Sample Column value**

> a:8:{s:18:"additional_charges";N;s:12:"salt_version";s:7:"NEWSALT";s:5:"sbemi";N;s:2:"si";s:1:"0";s:15:"mcpBaseCurrency";s:3:"INR";s:10:**"threeDSEci";s:2:"01"**;s:15:"threeDSEnrolled";s:1:"Y";s:13:"threeDSStatus";s:1:"A";}"

Comment: This does not look like JSON.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that it's JSON type.